# Docker run, no way to access application

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I m building an Express (nodejs) application that runs on the port 3000, with a simple hello world, and hoted to a public github repository.

Actually, it works great and the code simply looks like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I m studying docker and I want to make this little code work inside of a container, so I created this dockerfile :

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.17

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Install corresponding packages
# Git, pm2, curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  git \
  curl

# Downloading NodeJs v0.12
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Cloning repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/User/hello-world.git

# Install global dependencies
RUN npm install -g pm2

# Move inside of the project
RUN cd hello-world && npm install  && pm2 start app.js


# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Then I run these suit of command :

```
docker build -t hello-world
docker run -p 3000:3000
```

After this (and all is successful), when I try to access http://localhost:3000/ , The page is not found.

I need some help to understand my mistakes.

Thanks for all

Comment: your CMD command is not correct, it should be the last line of your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You should log-in to your running container:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
```

After getting inside the container, you can run your app there and debug directly inside the container.

something like:

```
cd your-directory/hello-world
```

Then:

```
node app.js
```

The console will spit out errors like your local development environment.

Comment: what did the console ouput show inside the container? It'll help others if you post it here in your question.

Comment: it runs as a daemon in fact

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your docker installation, it might not be available on localhost.
My installation is for instance not available on 127.0.0.1, but on 192.168.99.100.

The following hostsentry:

192.168.99.100 dockerhost

would allow me to access your app on  http://dockerhost:3000/

Hope that helps :-)